# Prove transformation between data types correctness

Tags: proof, agda

I have two data types and a transformation function to convert from one to another

```
data TTerm : Set where
   TVar : Nat -> TTerm
   TPrim : TPrim' -> TTerm
   TDef : QName -> TTerm
   TCon : QName -> TTerm
   TLam : TTerm -> TTerm
   TApp : TTerm -> List TTerm -> TTerm
   TLet : TTerm -> TTerm -> TTerm
   TLit : Literal -> TTerm
   TErased : TTerm
   TError : TError' -> TTerm

data GoTerm : Set where
  Self : GoTerm
  Local : LocalId -> GoTerm
  Global : GlobalId -> GoTerm
  GoVar : Nat -> GoTerm
  GoSwitch : GoTerm -> List GoTerm -> GoTerm
  GoCase : MemberId -> Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> List GoTerm -> GoTerm
  GoMethodCall : MemberId -> List GoTerm -> GoTerm
  GoMethodCallParam : GoTerm -> TypeId -> GoTerm
  GoCreateStruct : MemberId -> List GoTerm -> GoTerm
  GoIf : GoTerm -> GoTerm -> GoTerm -> GoTerm
  GoLet : String -> GoTerm -> GoTerm -> GoTerm
  PrimOp : GoTerm -> GoTerm -> GoTerm -> GoTerm
  ReturnExpression : GoTerm -> TypeId -> GoTerm
  GoInt : Nat -> GoTerm
  Const : String -> GoTerm
  UndefinedTerm : GoTerm
  GoErased : GoTerm
  Null : GoTerm
```

I have also created additional function that maps back from GoTerm to TTerm, so now I have two functions that do opposite things and would like to prove that `a ≡ (decompileTerm (compileTerm a))`. But so far have not found a way to do that, maybe someone could put me on the right tracks here?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Does the usual approach of defining a function that returns a proof of type `a ≡ (decompileTerm (compileTerm a))` and using pattern matching on all the different cases not work?

Comment: it works if I do it for primitive ones, like TErased, but it does not work for example for TLet, because I need to give concrete values for arguments of TLet (e.g. TLet ((TVar 0) (TPrim p)) and then give exact value for each possible p value), but that does not work for me, as there would be an insane amount of combinations possible

Comment: Could you give a smaller example of your problem with maybe one or two constructors and the compilation and decompilation functions for those? I think that would make this question easier to answer.

Comment: This question lacks necessary information, like the compilation and decompilation functions.  On the other hand, it gives excessive information on the data types: focus on a few constructors to illustrate the problem.